# Why can't I find iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.GetSubjectFields?

Tags: itext

I am trying to find the method:

> iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.GetSubjectFields()

..of iText and it isn't there. Has the library chaged?

I have included all assemblies:

```
itextsharp.dll
itextsharp.pdfa.dll
itextsharp.xtra.dll
```

I try to use this functionality : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825431/2173353

What am I missing?

I think that, according to [this](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/9ef8d2b4-ecb8-9e40-defb-cdc4d9742b7c.htm), it should be there!

Comment: OK. I got it. It's now: iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields()
God bless "Object Explorer"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK. I got it.

It's now: `iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields()`.
God bless "Object Explorer"!

Comment: Great, also thanks for Object Explorer tip. Now I can find anything that changed in a new version of any library.