# How to know which certificate used to sign my pdf document c#?

Tags: c#, itext, x509certificate

I have already signed document, and I need to know subject or issuer for that certificate. 
I use itextsharp and Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates for signing document.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: You should see [How to identify which root CA does the client certificate use?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94793/how-to-identify-which-root-ca-does-the-client-certificate-use).

Comment: you don't understand my problem.
I have pdf document which already signed, when I upload that document on my app, I should be read which certificate used for digitally sign.

Comment: What have you tried up to now ? Have you already got the signature from the PDF file? Have you already parsed this signature?

Comment: No, i don't know how to get signature form the PDF file. I only checked signature field
 AcroFields fields = r.AcroFields;
List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();

if (names.Count > 0)
pdf file is already signed. 

but i don't know which certificate used for that.

Comment: There's a search box in the top of stackoverflow web page. Have you already tried searching there?

Comment: [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823240#9825431)